# For Loop in Python using Jupyter

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to Take inputs from user to make a list and Again take one input from user and search it in the list and delete that element, if found.

I need to use for loop and this must be done in jupyter notebook cell
1)I could get a list of elements(list_2) from the user as input 
2)Problem is I am unable to use the second input from the user further in the for loop to check and delete in from the list.

Please help!! attached is the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: try `x=int(input('enter input)`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: _I am unable to use the second input from the user further in the for loop to check and delete in from the list._ You're unable to? Can you be more specific? Also, how is the issue related to Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: thanks for letting me know about the images thing. As I am new here so not sure about this. But will take care of this in future

Comment: my second question is: After I take a list of elements in my first list, now again I will ask the user to give an input as which element from my first list has to be deleted and display the new list

Answer (score 0):

1)I am not exactly sure about what you are talking about but I think this might help. So, Basically you can't take input in the form of a list from the user. Instead there are two ways you can do it:

A) **Using Loop**

```
list2=[]
number_of_elements= int(input('Number of elements that you want in your list.'))
for i in range(number_of_elements):
        new_element= int(input('Enter element:'))
        list2.append(new_element)
```

B) **Using split() function**

```
list_in_string_form= input('Enter elements and leave space to divide it.')
list_new= list_in_string_form.split() #Please read more about using split()
```

Just play with these methods a little. Best of luck :-)